# how to implement search view on FirebaserecyclerviewAdapter with oncreatoptions menu?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I know that we have to do the orderbyChild(_) and start At and End At, however i am passing  options to adapter, getting confused how to make use of this query at my project

below is  options

```
  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.randomeinfo, container, false)

    rc_listing  = view.rc_list
    rc_listing.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL , false)
    var options : FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Data?> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Data>()
        .setQuery(db, Data::class.java)
        .build()

    mAdapter = Rand_Adapter(options)
    rc_listing.adapter = mAdapter

    return view
```

Which is going to my Adapter and in the same fragment  i used oncreatptionmenu

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu)
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionsearch)
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    searchView.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

          //here what shall i pass 
         

            return false
        }
    })
}
```

Does it mean i have to create one more arraylist  i am really getting confused, on internet i found solution called as Elasticsearch however i do not think that is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the `query listener` to the `SearchView`, grab the query and perform `filter` search to show whatever data has to be presented to the user.
You can show and filter results in another activity or present one if the activity is empty.
If we assume doing this in another activity take query and handle a intent, like this.

```
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                handleIntent(query);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

```
    private void handleIntent(String query) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SearchActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_QUERY_STRING, query);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

In SearchActivity:

```
public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_QUERY_STRING = "SEARCH_QUERY";
```

Get query from intent we received in `onCreate()`

```
String result = getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_QUERY_STRING);
// Create new function
performFilter(query)
```

Now you have the query and create operation or task to filter on your data and produce new list.

Example:

```
    List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    private void performFilter(String result) {
        String[] stringList = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
        for (String currentItem : stringList) {
            if (currentItem.toLowerCase().trim().contains(result)) {
                filteredList.add(currentItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

This might not be exactly in your case, so take as reference.